# 2つの集合から1つずつ非復元抽出するときの抽出方法を列挙したい

Tags: python, python3

タイトルが分かりにくく申し訳ありません．

同じ長さの集合{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}があったとして，要素が空になるまで両方の集合から非復元抽出するものとします．例えば，次の抽出が考えられます．

例1: (1,4), (2,5), (3,6)
例2: (1,5), (2,6), (3,4)

考え得る全ての抽出法を列挙するプログラムを書きたいです．
2つの集合の長さは等しいものとします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint

a = {1,2,3}
b = {4,5,6}

result = [[*zip(a, p)] for p in permutations(b)]
pprint(result)

#
[[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]
```